Application.GetOpenFilename for a UNC without using Kernel32
My company has recently instituted some significant security upgrades that disallows the calling of Kernel32.dll using VBA.  Without this I can't call Application.GetOpenFilename and set the network path as the default location.  Is there another alternative?  I suppose I can require everyone to assign a drive path on their local machine but this is a last resort.

Using an API call from kernel32.dll does not change kernel32.dll, so there's no reason you can't continue to use GetOpenFilename. If you're not allowed to use kernel32.dll,  then Windows itself shouldn't be able to use it, which means Windows won't work, which means you'll need to install a different OS. I'm sure that's not what is intended, and that you've misconstrued what the actual policy means.

@KenWhite my macro files were disabled until I excluded the normal Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long.  This was some policy change that is meant to temper data exfiltation and such.  Our copy/paste activity likewise goes through screening.  So whatever the usage of Kernel32 it is disallowed in the VBA context.

To be clear, this question is about setting a UNC default file path using GetOpenFilename without SetCurrentDirectoryA.

Perhaps try: CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory = "\\xxxx\yyyy"
